# Compile error when using Spark to save data to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I'm trying to read data from Hbase and write to MongoDB, my code as following in scala:

```
mongoConfig.set("mongo.output.uri", "mongodb://node1:57017/sampledb.sample")
mongoConfig.set("mongo.output.format","com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat")
val documents:RDD[Map[Object, BasicBSONObject]] = newRDD1.map(f => convert2BSON(f))

documents.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file:///test",classOf[Object],classOf[BSONObject],
classOf[BSONFileOutputFormat[Object, BSONObject]],sparkConf)
```

But it got the following compiling error:

```
error: value saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile is not a member of 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Map[Object,org.bson.BasicBSONObject]]
```

I'm using Spark1.5.2, mongo-hadoop-core 1.5.2 and mongo-java-driver 3.2.0
My mongoDB version is 3.2.5

Comment: `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile` is accessible only to `RDD[(K, V)]` and you're trying `RDD[Map[Object,org.bson.BasicBSONObject]]` so error is to be expected.

Comment: Thank you so much, when I search the source code of RDD, when I can not find the function of saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile()?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

Comment: Thank you very much, can I ask a quick question please, when I ran: documents.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file:///this-is-completely-unused",classOf[Object],classOf[BSONObject],classOf[BSONFileOutputFormat[Object, BSONObject]],mongoConfig), Spark save the data to hard disk as /this-is-completely-unused rather than MongoDB, any where I miss configured please?

Comment: I think you'll need `MongoOutputFormat` not  `BSONFil‌​eOutputFormat`